# Send id as a parameter in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How do i set the id parameter for the *getNumberOfTasks()* ? The id parameter should have the value of id field from the database. I have done *$entities->getId()* but i get an error like *Trying to get property of non-object*
DefaultController.php

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('TestBundle:Projects')->findAll();
    $tasks = $em->getRepository('TestBundle:Tasks')->getNumberOfTasks($entities->getId);
    /*dump($entities);
    die();
    */


    return $this->render('TestBundle:Default:index.html.twig', [
                'projects' => $entities,
                'tasks' => $tasks,
            ]
    );
}
```

Tasks Repository

```
public function getNumberOfTasks($id)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
               ->where('p.projects = :id')
               ->setParameter('id', 1)
               ->getQuery();
    return count($qb->getResult());
}

public function getNumberOfCompletedTasks($id)
{ 
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
               ->where('p.projects = :id','p.completed = 1')
               ->setParameter('id', 1)
               ->getQuery(); 
    return count($qb->getResult());
}

public function getPercentComplete($id)
{
    $numberOfTasks = $this->getNumberOfTasks($id);
    $numberOfCompletedTasks = $this->getNumberOfCompletedTasks($id); 

    if($numberOfTasks == 0)
            return 100;

    return ($numberOfCompletedTasks / $numberOfTasks) * 100;
}
```

Comment: I think you could access the tasks in twig. Can you show us the entities, too?

Comment: `$entities` - is a single object, or an array of objects?

Comment: @ZsoltGyöngyösi yes i have tried it using {{ projects.tasks|tasks}} which did gave me the total number of tasks.But here I want the total number of tasks to calculate the percentage of remaining tasks.

Comment: @xurshid29 since I am using findAll(), I get it in array of Objects()

Comment: @RajShakya I think your logic is wrong..

Comment: @xurshid29 can u tell me how can i make it right?

Comment: Your error is pretty much clear: this isn't neither doctrine2 nor symfony2 issue, is php one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:
`$entities = $em->getRepository('TestBundle:Projects')->findAll();` is returning an array of objects.

You should iterate in entities if you want to have the id:

```
foreach ($entities as $entity) { 
    $tasks[] = $em->getRepository('TestBundle:Tasks')->getNumberOfTasks($entity->getId);
 }
```

and then iterate in twig for the `tasks`

Comment: what if I have to loop the tasks inside another loop?

Comment: You can, but I advise, to revise a bit the architecture, and use a join to make a single request to the database in your repository, doctrine is not the fastest thing ever, the lesser request to the database the better.